# Can a .exe compiled from C++ run standalone from Win 2000 onwards?

Tags: c++, windows, programming-languages, exe

I'm developing an application which shall be run on Windows servers and clients Win2K and higher. It's coded in AutoIT, a Windows-based test automation scripting language, but the security code analysis tool used by my client (a govt agency) doesn't support that language, so there's a concern the application may not be approved.

I'm searching for an alternative language to develop the tool in. The compiled .exe cannot require any additional runtime dependency that's not already installed in the production system - no one's interested to go through the red tape for a 10+ year old legacy system retiring in 2023. That means no runtime dependency on Python or .NET, for starters. Tentatively no JRE either. Not sure what other software I should check for.

This application only needs to run on Windows. After Googling, it seems impossible to use C# without .NET installed. Another option is C++. Is a C++ .exe standalone? I've only ever coded in C++ 7 years ago in school, and I didn't need to submit compiled code back then. What other options are there available to me?

Comment: I'm sure I know the answer, but why are you writing for something that old? That must be a constraint that someone gave you, right?

Comment: @Chipster It’s for a government agency.

Comment: A C++ program will most likely need the Visual C++ runtime it was built for. You should be able to find out from your client which versions have been cleared, and then use the appropriate SDK and toolchain.

Comment: The answer is highly compiler dependant. I use (an old version of) C++Builder myself, and can (and have) create self-contained EXEs that work all the way back to Win95, if I wanted to. Not that I ever need to do that nowadays. Win7 is my minimum deployment system, but I still write and test code on XP, too

Comment: @Chipster The application is supposed to help the software maintenance team in their routine work, as well as provide some basic troubleshooting support for users before engineers are called down to site. My particular department is dealing in legacy systems, some of which were deployed last decade such as mine. We haven't reached end-of-support yet, so the compatibility is still needed.

Comment: @molbdnilo does that mean that C++ also requires visual C++ as a runtime dependency, and isn't native to windows?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Go get [Visual Studio 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7873), This will enable you to build a C/C++ program that can be compiled as a standalone EXE and still run on Windows 2000 without additional dependency installations.  Use Google to find the download location of the service packs for VS2008.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2008):

> Visual Studio 2008 is the last version to support targeting Windows
>   2000 for C++ applications.

In Visual Studio, there is a project setting called **Runtime Library** that will enable your compiled EXE to statically link to the Visual Studio C/C++ runtime instead of taking the DLL dependency. I can't recall if VS2008 required the MSVCRT DLLs to be "copied" to the same directory as the EXE or formally "installed". So your best bet is to just use the statically linked Runtime Library option and not worry about it.   See picture below.  Assuming you aren't calling APIs that were introduced after Windows 2000, an EXE linked this way should just work when copied over to the target machine.

EXEs produced with newer versions of Visual Studio are not guaranteed to run on older versions of Windows. It's usually gated by the C-Runtime compatibility itself. That's why I'm pointing you to Visual Studio 2008 - it was the last supported version for targeting Windows 2000.

[image]

Comment: I did more in-depth checks this afternoon, and can confirm that all of the production servers I'm working with already have Visual C++ 2005 redist. installed, so this is the only thing I can work with. Is this a runtime environment for C++? Is there anything else I need? Also, is visual C++ the only way to build C++ apps? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the deployment aspect of C++.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - if you follow the instructions I have above, with setting the Runtime Library to "Multi-threaded" instead of "Multi-theaded DLL", you shouldn't have any issues getting compiled code to run on Windows 2000.  There are some options to using the DLL based runtime with VS2008 and copying those DLLs with your EXE. But if you are starting from scratch and aren't writing a monster amount of code, just stick with static linking to the CRT.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - what are you building?  A console application?  A gui based app?  Something else?

Comment: GUI. Partly diagnostic tool to help facilitate software maintenance, partly basic troubleshooting tool to reduce user reliance on on-site engineer support.

Comment: The production servers only have Visual C++ 2005 redist. Upgrades nor new installations are not possible except for security reasons. Will that change anything? Can I still use Visual Studio 2008 on my development machines?

Comment: Yes.  I keep telling you this.  You can compile your code on VS2008, just compile with `/MT` (Multi-Threaded) as the `Runtime Library` and your code will work just fine on Windows 2000 without having to worry about if a specific Visual C++ redist is installed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's because I've never compiled C++ before (last time I touched C++ I haven't even learnt OO concepts in univ). So what're you're saying is, by following the steps above, I can develop with VS2008 using the aforementioned settings, and the compiled .exe will be able to run on Win2K? Do you mean that it can run on Win2K regardless of what Visual C++ redist version is installed on the server, or do you mean that it can run on Win2K without needing any version of Visual C++ redist installed?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes