# exe file doesn't work outside visual studio 2022

Tags: c++

I've just installed visual studio 2022 current.Inside the environment everything works fine but i'd like to create a standalone executable. I have tried everything,downloaded microsoft c++ 2022 redistributable,the standalone build tools,tried debug and release version but when i click on the .exe of the project,nothing happens.
The program is the simple "hello world!".

Comment: What if you run it from the command line?

Comment: Are you using the correct Windows SDK? I think Visual Studio 2022 defaults to the Windows 11 SDK, it should work on Windows 10 but we all know that 'should' is never a definite. Also on Windows .exe files outputting to the command prompt will not launch the command prompt when you click on them, open cmd, go to your project directory / build (either x86 of x64) and type the name of your executable. You can use SHIFT+RIGHT CLICK in File Explorer to open a command prompt in your desired directory.

Comment: I have tried from the command line and it works :-)

Answer (score 7):

To successfully run an EXE you built in Visual Studio on another computer, that computer needs to have the Visual C++ runtime installed.  Install [these bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) on the target computer.

Alternatively, you can just link the EXE statically to the C++ runtime.  More details on how to statically link your EXE at [my old answer on this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56422591/104458)