# Issue with std::wstring when calling from c# with DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I was going to call an unmanaged function in a c++ library from c#, but it crashed. While troubleshooting I narrowed it down to std::wstring. A minimal example looks like this:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Start()
{
    std::wstring test = std::wstring(L"Hello World");

    return 2;
}
```

**C#**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("test.exe", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int  Start();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Start();

        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    }
}
```

This gives me a Stack overflow. If I remove the line with `std::wstring` or I change it to `std::string`, there is no problem and I get back 2.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: exporting functions from an EXE is very very strange, probably the exe's runtime has not been initialized (like set up its heap or even stack). It probably doable but as I said, very strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I noticed:

```
[DllImport("test.exe", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Exporting functions from an EXE instead of a DLL isn't standard.  (I think it can be done, but I wouldn't recommend it.)

Build your C++ code as a DLL instead of an EXE. [Statically link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421686/can-a-exe-compiled-from-c-run-standalone-from-win-2000-onwards/56422591#56422591) the DLL with the C++ runtime libraries to avoid missing dependency issues that could arise from not having the right DLLs in the loader search path.